# Why are `ngAfterViewChecked` and `ngAfterContentChecked` called twice?

Tags: angular

```js
import {
  AfterContentChecked,
  AfterViewChecked,
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ''
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked, AfterContentChecked {
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewChecked');
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked');
  }
}
```

This is literally everything I have in my Angular app and nothing else. Why are these methods called twice?

---

EDIT: I just found [this](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100#description):

> In development mode, Angular performs an additional check after each change detection run, to ensure the bindings haven't changed.

So I ran these commands to check if these methods are called only once in production, but they are run twice too:

```
ng build --configuration=production
cd dist/my-app
npx http-server
```

Why are they run twice in production? Doesn't it contradict what the documentation says? Should I report this as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

`ngAfterViewChecked` and `ngAfterContentChecked` lifecycle hooks to be called during every change detection completes. In this case

1. First call:

   - `ngAfterContentChecked`: called after ngAfterContentInit() and every subsequent ngDoCheck().
   - `ngAfterViewChecked`: called after the ngAfterViewInit() and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().
2. Second call:

   - After the initial call, Angular runs a second change detection cycle to ensure that all changes have stabilized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found an article in the Angular docs that say this should only happen in development but apparently it also happens in production. Do you know why this could be? See the edit of my question.

Comment: As I understand it, in development mode, an additional mechanism is in place to check and issue a warning when you attempt to modify something in your component after it has been checked once. This is used to display the "NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked" warning for developers. It is not related to when the change detection cycle runs after initialization.

Comment: After some research I realized your answer is wrong. Take a look at my answer to understand why. I upvoted your answer assuming you were right but now that I know you aren't StackOverflow doesn't allow me to remove undo the upvote. Would you mind editing your answer to let everyone know you aren't right?

Answer (score 0):

The `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ngAfterViewChecked` functions **ARE NOT RUN** in the second change detection cycle that runs in development to make sure the result is consistent. The change detection cycle is run, among other things, when a timeout times out.

As ahmedayman94 concluded in [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7055#issuecomment-812489264):

> So the best way to know if change detection has triggered for the
> bindings of a given component is not the ngAfterViewChecked, but
> instead having a getter and using its value in its template, a console
> log in that would fire if a proper CD on its bindings have triggered

This code demonstrates this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '{{ obj.foo }}'
})
export class AppComponent {
  obj = {
    get foo() {
      console.log('Change detection cycle');
      return 'Hello world!';
    },
  };
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('TIMEOUT!');
    }, 3000);
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewChecked');
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked');
  }
}
```

The output you get in the console is the following:

```
ngAfterContentChecked
Change detection cycle
ngAfterViewChecked
Change detection cycle
ngAfterContentChecked
Change detection cycle
ngAfterViewChecked
Change detection cycle
TIMEOUT!
ngAfterContentChecked
Change detection cycle
ngAfterViewChecked
Change detection cycle
```

With this output we can deduce that:

- On startup, the change detection cycle is run not twice, but 4 times. I'd love to know why, but I am unable to find any explanation anywhere.
- Timeouts trigger a change detection cycle.
- The second change detection cycle that is run to make sure the result is consistent does not trigger `ngAfterContentChecked` or `ngAfterViewChecked`.

> `ngAfterContentChecked` refers to the content inside `<app-root></app-root>`. It doesn't have any content but if we had `<app-root>something</app-root>` in `index.html` then it would have something. This is why this hook runs before the change detection cycle. If we had a way to detect the change detection cycle being run from index.html instead of the template of AppComponent we would be able to see how this hook doesn't really run before the change detection cycle as the console log suggests. If we could somehow log the exact moment the change detection cycle actually begins, the log would look like this:
>
> ```
> Change detection cycle
> ngAfterContentChecked
> ngAfterViewChecked
> Change detection cycle
> Change detection cycle
> ngAfterContentChecked
> ngAfterViewChecked
> Change detection cycle
> TIMEOUT!
> Change detection cycle
> ngAfterContentChecked
> ngAfterViewChecked
> Change detection cycle
> ```
>
> One way to demonstrate this is with a child component by making the parent log `Change detection cycle` in the getter and `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ngAfterViewChecked` in the child.

Comment: I appreciate your research efforts. However, please compare it with the original Angular documentation for a more accurate understanding. You can refer to Angular's official documentation on lifecycle in this link: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. This article provides detailed information about the lifecycle event sequence and demonstrates all the hooks, etc.